# ActiveRecord validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm wondering if its possible to have active record hold off on validating records for a short time? For example, in my webapp I have a table called `Sizes` that contain an attribute called `sort_order`, users are able to reorganize the order in which sizes are displayed by modifying the `sort_order`. When they do that I have this function which will go through the list of sizes and recalculate the sort order, updating the column accordingly.

```rb
  def update_size_order
    @size_ids = params[:categories]
    n = 0
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @size_ids.each do |temp|
        temp = temp.split('_')
        id = temp[1]
        size = Size.find(id)
        size.sort_order = n
        n += 1
        size.save!
      end
    end
    render :json => {}
  end
```

The problem arises because in my model I have

```rb
validates :sort_order, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

but when the model tries to save `size` I get an error because size isn't necessarily unique. Is there a way I can have ActiveRecord not execute validations until this function has finished? My googling skills have met their match so it seems, but I feel like there is a simple workaround for this problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `size.update_attribute :sort_order, n` instead of `save!`. It will simply update the database without running any form of validation. Since you're running this in a transaction, you should be OK, but generally you should avoid `update_attribute` for the very reason that it bypasses validation and callbacks.

Also, `each_with_index` is your friend:

```
def update_size_order
  @size_ids = params[:categories]

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @size_ids.each_with_index do |temp,n|
      temp = temp.split('_')
      id = temp[1]
      Size.find(id).update_attribute :sort_order, n
    end
  end
  render :json => {}
end
```

Since you're only interested in updating the attribute, you can also skip the entire process of instantiating an AR object, and drop your `Size.find(id)` call in favor of using [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all). This will silently ignore any IDs that aren't found, but it will drastically improve the performance of your loop as you're *halving* the number of queries being run. Instead of a `select` query, followed by fully instantiating an AR model, and an `update` for every single record, it will generate only the `update` query:

```
  @size_ids.each_with_index do |temp,n|
    temp = temp.split('_')
    id = temp[1]
    Size.where(id: tmp[1]).update_all(sort_order: n)
  end
```

Comment: would you still recommend using update_all even though its depreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you put this :

```
validates: :sort_order,
           presence: true,
           uniqueness: true,
           on: :create
```

Is that what you wanted ?
In this way, your validation execute only on creating new object .